# Finding a Pointer to NULL

Tags: c++, casting, null, c++03, nullptr

I have `int* foo[SIZE]` and I want to search it for the first element that points to `NULL`.

But when I do this:

```
 std::find(foo, foo + SIZE, NULL)
```

I get the error:

> error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const int' to 'int *'

Should I just be using `static_cast<int*>(NULL)` instead of `NULL`?

<sub>C++11 solves this via [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) but that's not an option for me in C++03</sub>

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] as usual please.

Comment: @Jarod42 `nullptr` edited out as it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: `NULL` is `0`, and doesn't have pointer type and is deduced as integer type, thus the error.

Comment: Because I'm tired. Deleting.

Comment: `static_cast<int*>(NULL)` is suitable, yes

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `nullptr` is C++11's solution to this problem. It's difficult to see how that doesn't have anything to do with the question. Perhaps if I edit the question to explain that it would make more sense to leave the tag?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wait, is `find(foo, foo + SIZE, NULL)` not the MCVE? I mean I guess I could show you me populate `foo` but I'm not sure if that would be helpful. It contains `int*`s and `NULL`s.

Comment: @JonathanMee Did you mean `std::find()`? Then probably yes. But it would have been clearer if written explicitly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry I always do `using namespace std` at the start of my toy examples, so I don't think about showing the namespace. Anyway I have edited for clarity.

Comment: @JonathanMee _"Sorry I always do `using namespace std`"_ Oh my. You are at least aware that's frowned upon in production code I hope.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeah I never do that in production code. But always in toy examples since I'll only be working with standard functions in them anyway.

Comment: @M.M Thanks, I felt more comfortable pursuing `static_cast<int*>` with your blessing. Incidentally, my research led me to as definitive proof as possible that `static_cast<int*>(NULL)` is the preferred solution; in the form of a comment from Bjarne Stroustrup and Herb Sutter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042775/2642059

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is actually called out in Herb Sutter and Bjarne Stroustrup's: [A name for the null pointer: `nullptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf):

> *Distinguishing between null and zero.* The null pointer and an integer 0 cannot be distinguished well for overload resolution. For example, given two overloaded functions `f(int)` and `f(char*)`, the call `f(0)` unambiguously resolves to `f(int)`. There is no way to write a call to `f(char*)` with a null pointer value without writing an explicit cast (i.e., `f((char*)0)`) or using a named variable

So we see that this problem can be solved by either:

1. An explicit cast
2. The declaration of a value with matching type, for example: `const int* piNULL = NULL`

Ideally when using the explicit cast a C-Style cast can be avoided. Either of these C++-Style casts effectively returns an `int*` containing address `NULL`:

- `reinterpret_cast<int*>(NULL)`
- `static_cast<int*>(NULL)`

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL asserts that:

> A null pointer constant may be implicitly converted to any pointer type; such conversion results in the null pointer value of that type

And since [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast):

> Converts between types using a combination of implicit and user-defined conversions

`static_cast` more closely defines the type of cast intended than does [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) which:

> Converts between types by reinterpreting the underlying bit pattern

So, **in C++03 `static_cast<int*>(NULL)` is the tightest inline definition of C++11's `nullptr` that can be achieved**.

Comment: Sorry to be dense, but what does this add that my answer doesn't already have?

Comment: @GManNickG 1)Proof that `nullptr` is not available in C++03 2)Definition of the options available in C++03 3)Consideration for the best C++03 alternative to `nullptr` 4)The definitive C++03 cross platform solution

Comment: ...so I repeat. My answer already states nullptr is not in C++03, and suggests alternatives for C++03 (including the cast solution as well). Neither is the "best" or "definitive", but whatever floats your boat I guess.

Comment: @GManNickG To quote a few lines where your answer recommends implementation defined behaviors over a standard condoned behavior: "tl;dr: Use `nullptr`" and "There are various C++03 implementations of `nullptr` if you need one." If the question hadn't been tagged C++03 your answer would be correct, unfortunately it leads readers to believe that the solution the standard does offer, should be used "in a pinch". I find this misleading. Since the standard floats the C++03 boat I'm going to go with the answer that presents standard defined C++03 options.

Comment: Huh? Nothing about that is implementation-defined. You can write a class, with well-defined behavior, and use it in place of `nullptr`. Is writing classes no longer C++03 standard?

Comment: @GManNickG You are correct, I interpreted that to mean use [Microsoft's `__nullptr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ex65770(v=vs.100).aspx) or similar, which I would vehemently oppose. Given that you intended "There are various C++03 implementations of nullptr if you need one." to mean write your own C++03 `nullptr` your answer is greatly improved in it's intent in my mind.

Comment: Ah, I will try to clarify my answer then, this explains the confusion.

Comment: @GManNickG Thanks that's a lot clearer +1. Just to be up front I think I still prefer the `static_cast` method but you're right, now it is simply a mater of preference.

Answer (score 6):

tl;dr: Use `nullptr`, or define your own equivalent.

---

The problem is that `NULL` is some macro that expands to an integral constant expression with value zero. In order to call the function, `std::find` has to deduce the type and use the value (`0`).

You cannot compare `int*` with `int`, hence the error. As far as the function is concerned, you just passed it some regular old `int` that happens to be zero, and those cannot be converted to null pointers; they have to be integral constant expressions.

Normally `NULL` "works" because it's used in contexts where it isn't treated just as its integer form, e.g.:

```
if (ptr == NULL)
```

Because here it maintains its "integral constant expression" status, so converts to a null pointer of the compared-to type.

You should use `nullptr` if you're in C++11 or beyond, because this is actually a null pointer, not an integer that converts to it. What you've described is actually one of the motivating factors for introducing `nullptr`.

There are various C++03 implementations of `nullptr` if you need one. I have attached the classic implementation at the bottom of this answer.

Also, you should prefer `std::array` if possible (Boost has one if you need it), or at the very least use `std::begin` and `std::end` to get the array begin and end pointers (and again, there are implementations of this floating around):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int*, 8> foo = {};
    std::find(foo.begin(), foo.end(), nullptr);
}
```

---

All said, in a pinch casting to the null pointer of your type is a valid solution. `nullptr` is really just a short-hand for "a thing that converts to the null pointer of the needed type".

---

Here is a `nullptr` implementation, initially created by Scott Meyers:

```
const
struct nullptr_t {
    template <typename T>
    operator T*() const {
        return 0;
    }

    template <typename C, typename T>
    operator T C::*() const {
        return 0;
    }

  private:
    void operator&() const;

} nullptr = {};
```

The syntax looks a bit funny because we don't usually define a class and a variable at the same time. Obviously if you want to stay C++11 compatible, `nullptr` isn't a usable identifier. `null_ptr` or `nullpointer` are good alternatives.

Comment: `nullptr` is not in the C++03 standard. So this is not a viable solution. I did add it as a tag on the question because I knew it to be the C++11 solution to this problem.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I suspected. Use a C++03 implementation of it, then. See section 1.1 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf (which is just an excerpt from Scott Meyers' Effective C++).